# macOS Sierra 10.12.5 - localhost - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, localhost

after rebooting my Mac, I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on all browsers. Doesn't matter if my node app is running (or not) on 3000, 3001, 8080.

As a matter fact when I launch my node app it starts (so there's no obvious conflict with another app) but calls never arrive as if something is capturing them between the browser and node.

I don't have Apache or Nginx installed.

Same with curl

```
curl localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
curl localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wow!

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

In my case `process.env.PORT` and `${port}` was. The message in the console was giving me the feeling that the server was really running on the displayed port, but in fact it wasn't.

However, the surprise is that express was not complaining about receiving an undefined value as a port!...

I've opened a ticket here to gather more information about this behavior. 
https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3364

Comment: I reported to the node folks and it is confirmed bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14205